# SWIFTのIF文でタップした画像を他の画像に切り替える処理

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, optional

添付した画像のようにSTART画像をタップしたらPAUSE画像に切り替わるようにしたいのですが、できません。

※追記
xcodeでビルドは通るのですが、START画像をタップしても下記の画像にあるようなPAUSE画像に切り替わりません。START画像をタップしてもタップされた反応として少し色が変わってそのまま動かなくなります。

添付画像はXcodeのstoryboardで作成したデザインです。教材と全く同じによう書いているのですが、どこにミスがあるのか分かりません。ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コード

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //startPause outlet to change the start to the pause image
    //この丸いスタートボタンを動く変数
    @IBOutlet weak var startPauseOutlets: UIButton!

    //var to check the state of the startPauseButton to display the correct image
    var startPauseButtonStateCheck = true

   // @IBAction func startPausePressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   @IBAction func startPausePressed(_ sender: Any) {
       if startPauseButtonStateCheck{
           //教材では最後！だが、？にした方が良いと表示された・・・ので、？にしたら、動かなかったので!でやり直したら、動いた。しかし、結局、?でも動いたので、?で通してみる。
           //下記のif文がおかしいのか、startとpause両方の画像が出ない
           let pause = UIImage(named: "pauseButton") as UIImage?
           startPauseOutlets.setImage(pause, for: .normal)
           startPauseButtonStateCheck = false
       }else{
           let start = UIImage(named: "start") as UIImage?
           startPauseOutlets.setImage(start, for: .normal)
           startPauseButtonStateCheck = true
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if startPauseButtonStateCheck` の行にブレークポイントを設定して、1ステップずつ実行してみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/130615

Comment: 正直あなたのご質問は情報が足りなさすぎて、「あてもん」をする以外には回答の書きようがありません。「できません」と言うのは一体どう言う状態なのでしょうか?「ビルドが通らない」「ビルドは通って実行できるが、何かの実行時エラーが発生する」「ビルドも通って実行時のエラーも発生しないが実行結果が期待したものと違う」などなど、どうなっているのかを明記してください。(ご自身のご質問は「編集」ができるはずなので、編集して情報を付け加えてください。)また Чайка さんのコメントにあるような方法で、ボタンを押した時に`startPausePressed(_:)`メソッドが実行されているかどうか調べて、その結果もご質問中に含めてください。コードの断片だけ示されても、そのコードが動かなくなる可能性はいくらでも考えられます。延々と続く「あてもん」のチェックをしないでも済むよう、できるだけ多くの情報をご質問中に含めるようにしてください。

Comment: 至らぬ質問で申し訳ございませんでした。先程、追記しブレークポイントを実行してみました。ブレークポイントの結果、 @IBOutlet weak var startPauseOutlets: UIButton! が nil になっておりました。

Comment: ご質問の編集と情報の提供ありがとうございます。あれこれ注文をつけましたが、あなた自身の問題をできるだけ早く解決することと、このサイトがよくできたQ&Aのデータベースととして機能すること、両方を目指せるノウハウの一端ですので、何か開発上の疑問点があれば思い出していただければ光栄です。さて、問題点は無事に解決されたと解釈してよろしいのでしょうか? 無事に解決できた場合、一番解決に役立った回答を「承認」するのがこちらのサイトのお約束です。 Чайка さんの提示された手順で問題解決の糸口を発見できたのであれば、ぜひ承認をお願いします。

Comment: OOPer様、返信が大変遅くなってしまい誠に申し訳ございませんでした。どうやら画像の取り込み方に問題があったようです。画像を一旦削除してから貼り直すとちゃんと動きました。

Answer (score 0):

Xcodeで、`@IBOutlet weak var startPauseOutlets: UIButton`の左にある○か白丸になっていませんか？

Xcodeでstartとpauseが切り替わるインターフェース設計画面を開き、右上の○が2つ繋がったようなボタンを押し、左側の画面にユーザーインターフェース、右側に対応するソースコードの2画面構成にして下さい。

次に`@IBOutlet weak var startPauseOutlets: UIButton`の左の○を右クリックし、そのままstart/pauseボタンまでドラッグし、start/pauseボタンの色が変わったところでマウスボタンから手を離します。

すると、`@IBOutlet weak var startPauseOutlets: UIButton`の横の◯の中に黒い●が描かれた二重丸になると思います。

この状態でプログラムをもう一度ステップ実行してみてください。

`@IBOutlet`というキーワードは、ユーザーインターフェース部品を参照するよという宣言だけなので、どのユーザーインターフェース部品を参照するか？は、

- 宣言の横の○から参照したいユーザーインターフェース部品と右クリックからのドラッグで接続指定する
- ユーザーインターフェース部品を右クリックでソースコードまでドラッグし、この部品をどんな変数名でソースコードから参照するか指定する

のどちらかを行わないと、宣言しただけで値は自動では入ってくれません。

`startPauseOutlets`という変数の値が`nil`であると言うことから原因を推測してみましたので、確認してみて下さい。

最後になりますが、一番大事な情報は`startPauseOutlets`という変数の値が`nil`であると言うことで、アプリケーションを操作した結果何が起きたかを質問に追記するよりも、
デバッグ中に`startPauseOutlets`の中身が`nil`である事の方がプログラミングとしては大事ですので、質問は出来たアプリケーションを操作したが「どう言う風にしか動かない」よりも
どういうデバッグを行い、原因らしいところが見つかったがどうすればその原因を解消出来るのか？
という観点から質問して下さると、答えが集まりやすく、より適切なアドバイスがもらえると思います。

Comment: 返信が大変遅くなってしまい誠に申し訳ございませんでした。どうやら画像の取り込み方に問題があったようです。画像を一旦削除してから貼り直すとちゃんと動きました。

Answer (score 0):

返信が大変遅くなってしまい誠に申し訳ございませんでした。どうやら画像の取り込み方に問題があったようです。画像を一旦削除してから貼り直すとちゃんと動きました。

Comment: 解決方法のご投稿ありがとうございます。ご質問からかなり時間が経過しているので、自己回答でも「承認」が出来るかと思います。承認の操作もよろしくお願いします。最近のXcodeでは外部のリソースを取り込んだ時に、見かけ上プロジェクトに取り込まれているリソースが、ビルドの時にアプリに取り込まれない、なんて事象が起こる場合があるのでそのようなことが起こっていたのでしょうか。何か同じような事象で悩んでいる方々の役に立つ情報が追記できそうであれば、承認後でも編集可能なはずなので、よろしくお願いします。